# How tinder gets friend list from facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, tinder

I have seen many apps like Tinder and many other apps gets friends lists from facebook. When i login to these app they import all my friends list and sotre to their database. According to facebook doc it says only taggable friends are available through api which should be used to tag on user posts. But Tinder and other apps do not tag friends in the post. So I m curious to know how they get facebook friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/me/friends` gets all friends who authorized the App with `user_friends` too, so they most likely used Tinder already.

The answer in this thread explains everything you need to know: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)

Comment: Thank you bro. It makes sense.